# Giving my boss acess to a gmail account I was required to set up

Tags: communication

I was required to set up a gmail account for my work, now my boss wants access to my password to access my account. Is this smart, legal and can I use two passwords to access my account so I know who is sending what message to clients?

Comment: Is there any specific reason this account is gmail instead of a proper company email? (Which might have features to let others read your mail without you needing to share passwords)

Comment: The two password part is a question for a gmail forum.

Comment: Is it only to be used for work?  Did he say why he needs to be able to send and read messages with it?  That's what "access" means, right?  What industry/level is this?

Comment: You should also read the Gmail terms of service. They may forbid account sharing.

Comment: If you were required to set it up for your work and set it up during your work hours, I don't think it's correct to even consider the account _yours_. That said, even internal company accounts normally just have one person accessing them, so wanting to share an account is strange. Why can't your boss just create a separate gmail account?

Comment: Is the account name your name or the name of your company?

Comment: For those not familiar, many people use gmail.com for small to mid companies, and gmail does allow you to set up an account for your_company.com that is still gmail.

Comment: @jimm101 Yep at my last employer we had gmail with its own domain name. my_name@company.com was the address. This company was rather large, though. I think people are moving towards cloud base because it is cheaper than maintaining your own mail servers. However, they could easily access it, and maintain my account without me giving the password.

Answer (score 6):

So there's two things here:

The first is that if this account was set up for work purposes, I would have expected it to have been set up by your IT department. It wouldn't be `some.random.email@gmail.com` it would be `kathy.lastname@mycompany.com`. If you set it up by yourself, it's not his and he has no right to access it. You haven't listed what country you're in, but there are laws that protect email access, even in cases where the company owns the accounts. You'd want to consult a lawyer for more info on that.

The second is that there is no reason why he should need access to your account itself. If for some reason access to the account is actually needed, gmail has a baked in feature for that called delegates. [Here's the help article on it.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en)

However, I would expect this to only be used for something like "Kathy is on vacation this week, but we need to keep her projects going." Since you're using this for work-only purposes, I'd imagine that won't be a problem per se. That being said, I think it would be better for everyone if you just had an out-of-office for that and said contact Bossy McManagerface for any questions during my absence.

tl;dr - if possible, just set up out of office. If you can't do that, set up a delegate.

Comment: Depending on the job, it might very well be `some.random.email@gmail.com`

Comment: Small businesses very well might have gmail addresses.  If they're too small for their own mail system the use of one of the biggies wouldn't surprise me.  I've dealt with multiple small companies where the addresses were gmail.

Comment: @LorenPechtel If you can afford even a minimum wage employee, you can afford $5.00 a month for a professional email account. It is trivial to set up.

Comment: Trivial for a professional to set up--I'm talking about companies that don't have such a person.

Comment: "If you set it up by yourself, it's not his and he has no right to access it." She was specifically asked and paid to set up an account for company purposes so per default she has exactly no rights to keep it. She did not mention that she was allowed to use it for personal mails so I assume that it is normal company property. It's a different story if the boss wants to impersonate her, but she did not mention anything like that.

Comment: My company has company email but also requires you to have an itunes account for you company issued iphone.  As far as I know, the itunes account is considered yours, but you are required to download an app that the company uses to maintain security and such (since the phone isn't yours).

Comment: @FooBar The law disagrees with you on that statement in many jurisdictions.

Comment: @corsika: any examples?

Comment: @FooBar For starters, the US. Because the Gmail account is third party, it calls under the Stored Communications Act. The fact that an employer *asked* her to set it up is irrelevant, as is the nature of the email. She entered into an agreement between her and Google to use Google's service. The employer is entirely third party and would have to go through the court system to compel access, legally.

Comment: @LorenPechtel IF you had to hire an external resource to set it up, it might cost a hundred or two. Tops. However, my brother in law was able to set his up with zero computer training - he just followed Google's docs for setting up Google Apps for Business.